# How to make a 3D object to follow my finger from left to right on Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, unity-remote

I'm new to unity and game developing so I've tried to make a game. Everything worked well until I thought about changing from making the game from PC to Android.

The movement on PC worked well but I can't seem to find any code for kind of the same movement for Android.

This is what I use for the PC movement

```cs
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewayForce = 500f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I used for the android movement but the only problem is that it doesn't go forward and a player doesn't even move. This script somehow moves the platform that the player is on.

```cs
public class PlayerMovANDROID : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    GameObject hitObj;
    RaycastHit hit;
    private float speed = 1;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10))
                    {
                        hitObj = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:

                    // If the finger is on the screen, move the object smoothly to the touch position          
                    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
                    if (hitObj != null)
                        hitObj.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, hitObj.transform.position.z));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GUI buttons to move the player?

If not you can use:
 horizontal= `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`  and
 vertical =`Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` to detect where the player has placed their finger on the screen.

Once you get those you should assign them to the object through Transform through

```
transform.Rotate(horizontal, vertical ,z);

transform.Translate(horizontal, vertical ,z);

transform.position(horizontal, vertical ,z);
```

Check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks but i figured out what i did wrong. Everything works now!